# Function to return IDs of points in quadrant of N x M grid

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a 2D game based on a board of N x M squares (really N x N since it's square). Each square in the board has an ID assigned, starting with ID `0` counting from left-to-right, top-to-bottom.

Example, for a board of 10 x 10

```
| 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  |
| 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 |
| 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 |
|             etc               |
|             etc               |
|             etc               |
|             etc               |
|             etc               |
```

I would a like a function, which takes the size of the grid (`N`) and a quadrant (one of `[0, 1, 2, 3]` corresponding to top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right), that returns the IDs of the elements in each quadrant. For example, `getQuadrant(10, 0)` would return the IDs in the top-left quadrant:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24... 44]
```

I've tried a few sequence solvers to find an equation but they're unable to find a match. The only working solutions I've come up with are quadrant dependent, meaning I have essentially have 4 functions.

Comment: Assuming you have an array of arrays you can get results in 2 loops the size of floor(n/2)  `arr.push(grid[i][j]`

Comment: What is 10 in `getQuadrant(10, 0)`?

Comment: The first param, 10 in the example, would be the length of one side of the grid. So a 10 would mean a 10x10 grid.

Comment: @Mihai - I'm currently storing the grid as a single array of length `N * N` - `[0, 1, 2, 3... N*N-1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary:**

The following expression evaluates to an array of the ids from an `n`x`n` square in quadrant `quad`:

```
Array.from({length: n * n / 4}).map((_,i) =>
  2 * i - i % (n / 2) + (quad % 2) * n / 2 + (quad > 1) * n * n / 2
)
```

**Details:**

The function below includes a single formula that allows you to enter N and M for a rectangular grid of any size (N & M must be even), as well as the quadrant number (0 to 3). The first example used is a 6 x 4 grid.

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23
```

```js
const getRectQuadrant = (n, m, quad) =>
  Array.from({length: n/2 * m/2}).map((_,i) =>
    2 * i - i % (n / 2) + (quad % 2) * n / 2 + (quad > 1) * n * m / 2
  );

console.log(JSON.stringify(getRectQuadrant(6, 4, 0)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getRectQuadrant(6, 4, 1)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getRectQuadrant(6, 4, 2)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getRectQuadrant(6, 4, 3)));
```

To generalize this to a square grid (i.e. M = N), just create another function that calls that one, i.e. `const getSquareQuadrant = (n, quad) => getRectQuadrant(n, n, quad);` or just replace every `m` in the above code with `n` as shown in the following code for a 4 x 4 square grid:

```
 0  1  2  3
 4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15
```

```js
const getSquareQuadrant = (n, quad) =>
  Array.from({length: n * n / 4}).map((_,i) =>
    2 * i - i % (n / 2) + (quad % 2) * n / 2 + (quad > 1) * n * n / 2
  );

console.log(JSON.stringify(getSquareQuadrant(4, 0)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getSquareQuadrant(4, 1)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getSquareQuadrant(4, 2)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getSquareQuadrant(4, 3)));
```

**Explanation for the rectangular N x M grid:**

```
Array.from({length: n/2 * m/2}).map((_,i) => ...
```

This creates a sequence of whole numbers (i.e. starting from zero) whose length is the length of one quadrant, i.e. the length of one quarter of the original grid. These sequential numbers are passed forward as `i`.

```
2 * i - i % (n / 2) + (quad % 2) * n / 2 + (quad > 1) * n * m / 2
-------------------   ------------------   ----------------------
creates the values    adds a constant if   adds a constant if you
in the top left       you want the right   want the bottom half
quadrant              half
```

**More verbose/readable version for rectangular grid:**

```js
const getRectQuadrant = (m, n, quad) => {
  const quadrantPlaceholders = Array.from({length: n/2 * m/2});
  const offsetForRightHalf = (quad % 2) * n / 2;
  const offsetForBottomHalf = (quad > 1) * n * m / 2;
  const idsForQuadrant = quadrantPlaceholders.map((_,i) => {
    const idForTopLeft = 2 * i - i % (n / 2);
    return idForTopLeft + offsetForRightHalf + offsetForBottomHalf;
  });
  return idsForQuadrant;
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(getRectQuadrant(4, 6, 0)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getRectQuadrant(4, 6, 1)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getRectQuadrant(4, 6, 2)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getRectQuadrant(4, 6, 3)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create such function using `for` loop where i is incremented by grid length. Then you just need to slice first or second half of grid based on quadrant parameter.

```js
var data = Array.from(Array(100), (e, i) => e = i)

function getQuadrant(data, n, quad) {
  var result = []
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += n) {
    var p = i + (n / 2)

    if (quad == 0 && i < data.length / 2) result.push(...data.slice(i, p))
    if (quad == 1 && i < data.length / 2) result.push(...data.slice(p, i + n))
    if (quad == 2 && i >= data.length / 2) result.push(...data.slice(i, p))
    if (quad == 3 && i >= data.length / 2) result.push(...data.slice(p, i + n))
  }
  return result
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getQuadrant(data, 10, 0)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(getQuadrant(data, 10, 1)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(getQuadrant(data, 10, 3)))
```